# Save a specific item from an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to save the specific model from an array to a variable in able to use it later. How can that be possible? I don't want to use a list as the user inputs the models from an .ini file and he can add as many as he want.

```
private static bool IsValidVehicleNearPlayer()
{
    Vehicle[] nearbyVehicles = API.Common.Player.GetNearbyVehicles(3);
    if (nearbyVehicles.Length >= 1 && nearbyVehicles.Any((Vehicle x) => Vector3.DistanceSquared(x.RearPosition, API.Common.Player.Position) < 6.25f && Settings.FireDepartmentVehicles.Any((string y) => string.Equals(y, x.Model.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))))
    {
        CloseVehicle = nearbyVehicles;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see the CloseVehicle is a mistake of course. How can I do something like that?

Comment: Instead of returning a `bool`, why not just return a `Vehicle`? Where you're returning `false`, return `null` instead.

Comment: The thing is that I need that bool as well for other checks in other parts of the code

Comment: Those other parts of the code can't just interpret a `null` return value as false and non-null as `true`? I'd still lean towards returning the vehicle from the method. Otherwise you'll end up with the "side effect" code smell. You could store the vehicle in a class member like it looks like you're doing in your code, but there's nothing really that says "calling the method will set that class member."

Comment: You could change the method to `TryXXX` pattern eg. `static bool TryGetValid(out Vehicle vehicle)` if you only need the return value and not the out call it like this `if (TryGetValid(out _))` if you need the vehicle call it like this `if (TryGetValid(out var vehicle)) { //use vehicle }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CloseVehicle = nearbyVehicles
    .FirstOrDefault((Vehicle x) => 
    Vector3.DistanceSquared(x.RearPosition, API.Common.Player.Position) < 6.25f &&
    Settings.FireDepartmentVehicles
        .Any((string y) => 
        string.Equals(y, x.Model.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
));
```

if `CloseVehicle` is a `Vehicle`.
You could then remove your `Any` check and `return CloseVehicle != null`.